# Mongoose - Delete document with all array values are greater than specific value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I currently have a `Chat` model which has an array named `deletedUsers` containing objects with the following format: `{deletionDate: Date, userId: Id}`.

I want to delete a `Chat` document if the `_id` matches the specified `id` and if **all** the `deletedUsers.deletionDate` values are greater than the current date.

This is the query I currently have:

```
await Chat.findOneAndDelete({
    $and: [{ _id: req.params.chatid }, {"deletedUsers.deletionDate":  {$gt: Date.now()}}]
})
```

The problem with this query is that it will **delete** a document even if the `deletionDate` is greater than the current date for **only one array element**. I only want the document to be deleted if this is **true** for all array elements, not just one.

I attempted to use the `$all` operator with this query, however, I got an error perhaps due to an incorrect use case of this operator.

This is an example of what a `deletedUsers` array would look like for  a typical `Chat` document:

```
deletedUsers array -
[{userId: Id, deletionDate: Date}, {userId: Id2, deletionDate: Date2}]
```

Any ideas on how to adjust this query to perform as expected? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All array elements with `deletionDate` must be greater than the current date is equivalent to any array element(s) with `deletionDate` must not be less than or equal to the current date (Negation).

```
(All) deletionDate: { $gt: new Date() }
= !((All) deletionDate: { $gt: new Date() })
= (Any) deletionDate { $not: { $lte: new Date() } }
```

```
await Chat.findOneAndDelete({
  $and: [
    { _id: req.params.chatid },
    {
      "deletedUsers.deletionDate": {
        $not: {
          $lte: Date.now()
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CZ-DG6fL9pG)

Comment: Thank you for the solution, however could you please further explain how this works. How does it match *all** array elements instead of one? thanks

Comment: Hi, from my query, it is a negation for matching all elements. So if there is any array element that is not fulfilled, the document will not be selected.